# Get JSON values from a list of pairs as Array (for autocomplete function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete, key-value

I retrieve a list of pairs from a JSON document.
I can retrieve each pair through

```
$.each(result,function(key,value)
{
    alert(key+" "+value);
}
```

but for certain cases, I would like to retrieve only each value, put it in an array so I can add it to an autocomplete function :

```
$("#myTextField").autocomplete({source:listOfValues});
```

But I cannot find how to construct the object "listOfValues".

I have almost no experiences in JQuery and JSON. (That's why I assume, my question is quite simple, but I cannot find the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map` function:

```
var dimensions = { width: 10, height: 15, length: 20 };
var keys = $.map( dimensions, function( value, key ) {
  return key;
});
```

Documentation [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = [];
$.each(result,function(key,value)
{
  list.push(value);
}

$("#myTextField").autocomplete({source:list});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an `Array` of object to hold your `listOfValues`, and while iterating over your JSON `result` push each element to the table:

```js
var listOfValues = [];
$.each(result,function(key,value)
{
  listOfValues.push(value);
}
//Some other JS stuff
$("#myTextField").autocomplete({
  source:listOfValues
});
```